# "prior" vs. "previous" work

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice, word-meaning

Are **prior** and **previous** interchangeable in this context?

> ... including datasets from previous work.

And,

> ... including datasets from prior work.

Can you clarify please what is the difference between them?

Comment: Related to this question: [Are prior, previous, and preceding interchangeable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/248416/are-prior-previous-and-preceding-interchangeable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that usage, they are 99% interchangeable - there is a slight hint that `prior` work refers to one's own work, whereas `previous` *might* refer to someone else's, but this is a very fine distinction.